# Problems With Maps and Streetview Javascript ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-street-view

I'm in charge of a geolocation project, but I've found some limitations.

One of them is that I have a slight perception that Map with Streetview can not work on divs or separate instances.

I have a tab (boottsrap) with sketch or map and in another tab the streetview which loads me but with black screen and I have to resize the screen so that it appears with normality.
I have done everything, but no results to this topic.

```
var esta = "vistaPanoramica";
var desplaza = true;
try {
    if (vjDebug) {
        muestras(esta, 'Inicio', 'Debug');
    };
    if (vjEstadoMap == "GRD") {
        desplaza = false;
    };
    vjPanoramica = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(divPanorama, {
        position: coordenadas,
        clickToGo: desplaza, // Desactiva el cuadro que acerca la imagen al entorno que encierra
        imageDateControl: false,
        linksControl: desplaza, // Activa el control de desplazarse con las flechas por las calles
        panControl: true,
        addressControl: false, // Activa el panel de leyenda de la Dirección
        enableCloseButton: false, // Desactiva el boton de salir de la vista panoramica
        fullscreenControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        pov: {
            heading: parseInt(vjPovHeading),
            pitch: -1
        }
    });
    if (vjEstadoMap != "GRD") {
        if (vjDebug) {
            muestras(esta, 'vjEstadoMap:' + vjEstadoMap, 'Debug', Mensaje);
        };
        if (vjDebug) {
            muestras(esta, 'vjEstadoSvw:' + vjEstadoSvw, 'Debug', Mensaje);
        };
        map.setStreetView(vjPanoramica);
    };
    // map.panTo(coordenadas);     muestras(esta, 'Centra el mapa con las coordenadas', 'Debug');            //vuelvo a centralizar el mapa con las coordenadas dadas    
    if (vjDebug) {
        muestras(esta, 'Centralizo vista panoramica con coordenadas recibidas', 'Debug', Mensaje);
    };
    vjPanoramica.addListener('links_changed', function () {
        //              alert(vjPanoramicaCreada);
        //              //alert(document.getElementById("mapacapturado").style.width.toString);
        //              if (vjEstadoMap == "GRD" && vjPanoramicaCreada){
        //                    
        //                    editarCaptura('vista2Mapas');
        //                }               
        muestras('vistaPanoramica', 'vjPanoramica.addListener.links_changed', 'informe');
        if (vjEstadoMap != "GRD") {
            if (vjDebug) {
                muestras(esta, 'vjEstadoMap:' + vjEstadoMap, 'Debug', Mensaje);
            };
            map.panTo(vjPanoramica.getPosition()); //vuelvo a centralizar el mapa con las coordenadas dadas  
            muestraNuevaUbicacion(vjPanoramica.getPosition());
        };
    });
    document.getElementById("MainContent_lbl_panoZoom").innerHTML = "Zoom:" + vjPanoramica.getZoom();
    vjPanoramica.addListener('zoom_changed', function () {
        vjpanorZoomUlt = vjPanoramica.getZoom();
        document.getElementById("MainContent_lbl_panoZoom").innerHTML = "Zoom: " + vjpanorZoomUlt;
        actualizaData("vjPanoramica.zoom_changed", vjMapas.getCenter(), vjMapas.getZoom(), vjPovHeading, vjPovPitch, vjpanorZoomUlt);
    });
    vjPanoramica.addListener('pov_changed', function () {
        vjPovHeading = vjPanoramica.getPov().heading + '';
        vjPovPitch = vjPanoramica.getPov().pitch + '';
        //                document.getElementById("lbl_iPovHeading").innerHTML = "H:" + vjPovHeading.substring(1, 6); 
        //                document.getElementById("lbl_iPovPitch").innerHTML = "P:" + vjPovPitch.substring(1, 6);  
        actualizaData("vjPanoramica.pov_changed", vjMapas.getCenter(), vjMapas.getZoom(), vjPovHeading, vjPovPitch, vjpanorZoomUlt);
    });
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: I think it's not for badly used code,

The problem is that when I put a div from the other the streetview appears black screen, when I put them together in the same div there is no problem

The size of the div is width: 100% and heigh: 640px

Comment: Who am I to judge your code mate. But that's the thing, you get solution after developer go through your code. Based on descriptions cannot solve your issue. A post without code, won't get much importance either.

Comment: I published the code of Panorama View in the original thread